# Ошибка синтаксиса dollar quoting postgresql в Yii2 Db execute()

Tags: php, yii2, postgresql

Создаю триггер с помощью миграции, PostgreSQL.
Делаю запрос напрямую в БД -> отрабатывает корректно: и функция, и триггер создаются.
Делаю запрос через миграцию -> получаю ошибку.

Файл миграции:

```
public function up()
{
    $this->execute('DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_window_view_before_del ON window_view;');

    $this->execute('DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS trigger_window_view_before_del();');
    $this->execute('
        CREATE FUNCTION trigger_window_view_before_del() RETURNS trigger AS $trigger_window_view_before_del$
        BEGIN 
        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM object_rent WHERE window_view ? OLD.id::text) > 0 THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION \'Sorry, cannot delete this window_view, because it used in object_rent.\';
        ELSIF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM object_sale WHERE window_view ? OLD.id::text) > 0 THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION \'Sorry, cannot delete this window_view, because it used in object_sale.\';
        ELSE
        DELETE FROM window_view WHERE window_view.id = OLD.id;
        END IF;
        END; 
        $trigger_window_view_before_del$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
    ');

    $this->execute('
        CREATE TRIGGER trigger_window_view_before_del 
        BEFORE DELETE ON window_view FOR EACH ROW 
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_window_view_before_del();
    ');
}
```

Текст ошибки:

```
> execute SQL: DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_window_view_before_del ON window_view; ... done (time: 0.009s)
> execute SQL: DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS trigger_window_view_before_del(); ... done (time: 0.001s)
> execute SQL: 
        CREATE FUNCTION trigger_window_view_before_del() RETURNS trigger AS $trigger_window_view_before_del$
        BEGIN 
        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM object_rent WHERE window_view ? OLD.id::text) > 0 THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Sorry, cannot delete this window_view, because it used in object_rent.';
        ELSIF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM object_sale WHERE window_view ? OLD.id::text) > 0 THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Sorry, cannot delete this window_view, because it used in object_sale.';
        ELSE
        DELETE FROM window_view WHERE window_view.id = OLD.id;
        END IF;
        END; 
        $trigger_window_view_before_del$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
     ...Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1" at character 201
The SQL being executed was: 
            CREATE FUNCTION trigger_window_view_before_del() RETURNS trigger AS $trigger_window_view_before_del$
            BEGIN 
            IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM object_rent WHERE window_view ? OLD.id::text) > 0 THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'Sorry, cannot delete this window_view, because it used in object_rent.';
            ELSIF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM object_sale WHERE window_view ? OLD.id::text) > 0 THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'Sorry, cannot delete this window_view, because it used in object_sale.';
            ELSE
            DELETE FROM window_view WHERE window_view.id = OLD.id;
            END IF;
            END; 
            $trigger_window_view_before_del$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
        '

in /src/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.php:636

Error Info:
Array
(
    [0] => 42601
    [1] => 7
    [2] => ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1" at character 201
)
```

Answer (score 0):

скорее всего проблема с PDO, возможно перед $ нужно поставить \

У меня выдавалась точно такая же ошибка (она у них видимо на все случаи жизни, если вдруг парсер не разобрался) на запрос

> created >= now() - interval :created

исправил на

> created >= now() - :created::interval

и ошибка пропала, хотя оба варианта работают, если делать запрос к базе через другие инструменты, а второй вариант наоборот должен выглядеть сложнее для парсера.
Такого рода ошибки наталкивают меня на мысль, что PDO не просто подставляет параметры, а анализирует запросы, что неизбежно должно сказаться на производительности.
На [гитхабе yii2](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6410) та же ошибка в совершенно элементарном случае.